# ACF object not returning data

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I'm creating a custom rest api endpoint to return custom post type with custom fields.

At this moment I have this:

```
function getPostVendaById( $request ) {
   // setup query argument
    $args = array(
        'p' => 4294,
        'post_type' => 'venda_de_casas',
    );

    // get posts
    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    // add custom field data to posts array 
    foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
        $posts[$key]->acf = get_fields($post->ID);
        $posts[$key]->link = get_permalink($post->ID);
        $posts[$key]->image = 
        get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

but this doesn't work until I go to my backend and update the custom post.

already tried `update_post ( $ID )` still not working, any help?

Comment: If you runing this right after you created new post, you can't get ACF because it takes some time to create post and then set post_meta values, same goes on update. Can you explain when you running this function

Comment: @Beneris check update pls

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

im making this to create entries on my custom post

```
$request = json_decode($request->get_body());
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title'=> 'e',
    'post_type'=> 'venda_de_casas',
    'post_status'  => 'publish')
);

add_post_meta($post_id, 'nome', $request->name, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'email', $request->email, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'telemovel', $request->phone, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'tipo', $request->type, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'preco', $request->price[0].'€' . ' - ' . $request->price[1].'€', true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'nº_quartos', $request->rooms, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'coordenadas', $request->coordinates->lat . ',' . $request->coordinates->lng, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'classe_energetica', $request->certificate, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'area_bruta', $request->maxArea, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'area_util', $request->utilArea, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'lugares_de_garagem', $request->garage, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'casas_de_banho', $request->bathrooms, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'distrito', $request->district->label, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'conselho', $request->concelho->label, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'freguesia', $request->freguesia->label, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'nº_quartos', $request->rooms, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'servicos_de_saude', $request->saude, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'zonas_verdes', $request->green, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'comercio', $request->comercio, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'escolas', $request->school, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'acessibilidade', $request->acessibilidade, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'cultura_e_lazer', $request->culture, true);

$images = array();

foreach($request->images as $image) {
    $image = uploadImageAndSave($post_id);
    array_push($images,$image);
    unlink($image);
}
update_field("field_5d2c5c78c5d0e", $images, $post_id );

$my_post = array(
    'post_type' => 'venda_de_casas',
    'ID' => $post_id ,
    'post_title' => 'e'
);

wp_update_post($my_post);
```

and then i made a custom api endpoint to getPostVendaById to get the custom post type by id, that call is made when i want to get that specific post, not after the creation

Comment: I think you don't need to run `wp_update_post()` if you try to get all acf right after inserting, as I mentioned those meta fields can be still on the way to post_meta table, so if you need that data right away, use them from $_REQUEST, also try to replace `get_fields()` with `get_post_meta()` I think ACF functions are set_field and get_field, if you adding them using `add_post_meta()` this might causes some issues, if those acf not registered using ACF functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to create the custom end point for custom post type instead you can use the default WordPress API call for custom post type:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/<post_type_name>/
```

And configure the **ACF to Rest API** plugin to your WordPress installation: https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api which expose your all acf fields of post type into the rest api response.

### Note:

Keep the below option true while creating the custom post type:

> 'show_in_rest' => true

Hope this helps!

Comment: not working for me, meaning that it doesn't appear in REST API as a separate field